# Images are not responsive to Max-Width property

Tags: css, html, image

I'm attempting to get my 'Slider' images to be more responsive. I'm fairly certain my issue is an inheritance problem.

If the 'slider' image is pulled out of the container div, they will resize based upon the window size.

However, the images do not resize to fit the window when in the div.

I have even tried inline css ***style="max-width:100%;"*** in the img tag, but it will not resize.

I have tried multiple variations to get the image to be more fluid.

Any help?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="slider"><img src="img/img1.png" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height:100%;
}


#container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 960px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#slider img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: By `max-width: 100%;` you should ask yourself: `100%` of what? width of the parent element? If so you have to specify the width of `#slider`-div as well. Something like `#slider { width: 100%; }` may work in this case.

Comment: I tried that too. Adding width of both 100% and 960px to sliders property. But it still wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: Have a look at: http://jsbin.com/gobuli/1/edit?html,css,output Besides, to have a fluid layout, the width of the container should be specified [in percentage](http://jsbin.com/gobuli/2/edit) not absolute length; Unless you want to use `@media` queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Only if you want text in there */
}
#slider img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="slider">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1000x300/000000/fff.jpg&text=Slide3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a **codepen** of your problem
http://codepen.io/sachya/pen/EutdJ

Comment: This was it. Changing my container to max-width instead of width! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the `width` instead of the `max-width` property?

```
#slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Do you have a url to see what you are trying to do?